# OpenCV - undefined reference: SurfFeatureDetector and BruteForceMatcher

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, undefined-reference, surf

I'm making a program in C++ that uses 2 images to detect SURF Features, compute the matches with a bruteforcematcher and draws it.

Here's the code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
        if (argc <3) {
            cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " imageLocation1 imageLocation2" << endl;

            return -1;
        }

        Mat source1 = imread(argv[1],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        Mat source2 = imread(argv[2],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        if(source1.empty() || source2.empty()){
        printf("Can't load all the images!");
        return -1;
        }   

//Initialise the Wrapping Class for Surf()
    SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);

//detect : first param: Image, second param: vector (output)

    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1,keypoints2;

    detector.detect(source1,keypoints1);
    detector.detect(source2,keypoints2);

//Initialise wrapping class for descriptors computing using SURF() class.
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

//Compute: Input:image, keypoints Output:descriptors
    Mat descriptors1,descriptors2;

    extractor.compute(source1,keypoints1,descriptors1);
    extractor.compute(source2,keypoints2,descriptors2);

//Initialise BruteForceMatcher: For each descriptor in the first set, this matcher finds the closest descriptor in the second set by trying each on (=brute)
    BruteForceMatcher< L2<float> > matcher;
    vector< DMatch > matches;

//match: execute the matcher!
    matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2, matches);

//Draw the matches with drawMatches
    Mat target;
    drawMatches(source1,keypoints1,source2,keypoints2,matches,target); 

    imshow("Matches", target);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Building isn't a problem, but when linking, I get this very nasty errors:

```
CMakeFiles/opg13.dir/src/lennart_martens_opgave13.o: In function `cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> >::~BruteForceMatcher()':
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv17BruteForceMatcherINS_2L2IfEEED2Ev[_ZN2cv17BruteForceMatcherINS_2L2IfEEED5Ev]+0xb): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::~DescriptorMatcher()'
CMakeFiles/opg13.dir/src/lennart_martens_opgave13.o: In function `cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> >::~BruteForceMatcher()':
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv17BruteForceMatcherINS_2L2IfEEED0Ev[_ZN2cv17BruteForceMatcherINS_2L2IfEEED5Ev]+0x12): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::~DescriptorMatcher()'
CMakeFiles/opg13.dir/src/lennart_martens_opgave13.o: In function `main':
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x172): undefined reference to `cv::SurfFeatureDetector::SurfFeatureDetector(double, int, int, bool)'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x24f): undefined reference to `cv::FeatureDetector::detect(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat const&) const'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x30a): undefined reference to `cv::FeatureDetector::detect(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat const&) const'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x346): undefined reference to `cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor::SurfDescriptorExtractor(int, int, bool, bool)'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x495): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorExtractor::compute(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat&) const'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4bb): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorExtractor::compute(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat&) const'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x5ac): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::match(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::DMatch, std::allocator<cv::DMatch> >&, cv::Mat const&) const'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x6de): undefined reference to `cv::drawMatches(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, std::vector<cv::DMatch, std::allocator<cv::DMatch> > const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x781): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::~DescriptorMatcher()'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x7ad): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x7b5): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorExtractor::~DescriptorExtractor()'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x7d8): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::SurfFeatureDetector'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x7e0): undefined reference to `cv::FeatureDetector::~FeatureDetector()'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x8c8): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::SurfFeatureDetector'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x8d0): undefined reference to `cv::FeatureDetector::~FeatureDetector()'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x942): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x94a): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorExtractor::~DescriptorExtractor()'
lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9a2): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::~DescriptorMatcher()'
CMakeFiles/opg13.dir/src/lennart_martens_opgave13.o:(.rodata._ZTVN2cv17BruteForceMatcherINS_2L2IfEEEE[vtable for cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> >]+0x10): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::add(std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/opg13.dir/src/lennart_martens_opgave13.o:(.rodata._ZTVN2cv17BruteForceMatcherINS_2L2IfEEEE[vtable for cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> >]+0x14): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::clear()'
CMakeFiles/opg13.dir/src/lennart_martens_opgave13.o:(.rodata._ZTVN2cv17BruteForceMatcherINS_2L2IfEEEE[vtable for cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> >]+0x18): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::empty() const'
CMakeFiles/opg13.dir/src/lennart_martens_opgave13.o:(.rodata._ZTVN2cv17BruteForceMatcherINS_2L2IfEEEE[vtable for cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> >]+0x20): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::train()'
CMakeFiles/opg13.dir/src/lennart_martens_opgave13.o:(.rodata._ZTVN2cv17BruteForceMatcherINS_2L2IfEEEE[vtable for cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> >]+0x24): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::read(cv::FileNode const&)'
CMakeFiles/opg13.dir/src/lennart_martens_opgave13.o:(.rodata._ZTVN2cv17BruteForceMatcherINS_2L2IfEEEE[vtable for cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> >]+0x28): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::write(cv::FileStorage&) const'
CMakeFiles/opg13.dir/src/lennart_martens_opgave13.o:(.rodata._ZTVN2cv17BruteForceMatcherINS_2L2IfEEEE[vtable for cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> >]+0x30): undefined reference to `cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> >::knnMatchImpl(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch, std::allocator<cv::DMatch> >, std::allocator<std::vector<cv::DMatch, std::allocator<cv::DMatch> > > >&, int, std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat> > const&, bool)'
CMakeFiles/opg13.dir/src/lennart_martens_opgave13.o:(.rodata._ZTVN2cv17BruteForceMatcherINS_2L2IfEEEE[vtable for cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> >]+0x34): undefined reference to `cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> >::radiusMatchImpl(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch, std::allocator<cv::DMatch> >, std::allocator<std::vector<cv::DMatch, std::allocator<cv::DMatch> > > >&, float, std::vector<cv::Mat, std::allocator<cv::Mat> > const&, bool)'
CMakeFiles/opg13.dir/src/lennart_martens_opgave13.o:(.rodata._ZTIN2cv17BruteForceMatcherINS_2L2IfEEEE[typeinfo for cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float> >]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for cv::DescriptorMatcher'
collect2: ld gaf exit-status 1 terug
make[2]: *** [bin/opg13] Fout 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/opg13.dir/all] Fout 2
make: *** [all] Fout 2
```

I really don't know what the problem is. I didn't find a thing at the Internet. Hope someone can help!

Edit: This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4)


PROJECT(LABO5)

# paths 
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(src)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/lib)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/usr/lib)
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-o3 -w")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "-pg")
SET(OpenCV_LIBRARIES opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc )


ADD_EXECUTABLE(opg13 src/lennart_martens_opgave13.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(opg13 ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
```

Comment: I am having the exact same problem , how did you include opencv_features2d ? I did SET(OpenCV_LIBRARIES opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc opencv_features2d) but it didn't work .

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you're using opencv 2.4, SURF and SIFT interfaces are changed to nonfree folder. You can use it by including this line

```
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
```

then you can use SurfFeatureDetector as before.

Comment: Add also as dynamic libraries to link libopencv_nonfree.so and libopencv_features2d.so

Answer (score 8):

For SURF, @Mingyi Wu have answered. For **BruteForceMatcher**, please

```
#include <opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using opencv2.4 or trunk from svn, SURF and SIFT interfaces are changed. 
http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog

Answer (score 0):

> I really don't know what the problem is.

The problem is most likely incorrect link line. Unfortunately, you didn't say what your link line *is*, so no further help could be given. Reading [this](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html) may be helpful.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot that. Edit first post.

Comment: Found it: I forgot to include a library(opencv_features2d).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after installing ROS. The problem was that I was linking to the wrong libraries.

I fixed the link errors by adding the following line to my CMakeLists.txt: `link_directories(/opt/ros/groovy/lib)`

Answer (score 0):

for ocv 2.4.9:`#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>` is the location of SURF. In project **Settings** select **Configuration Properties**, then **Linker**, then **Input** and then add **opencv_nonfree249d.lib** to **Additional Dependencies**. With those ones the following example from ocv documentation works fine :-) http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html#feature-detection

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem after upgrade OpenCV from 2.3.1 to 2.4.5, and I've solved this issue linking opencv_nonfree, and add the necessary headers for my project:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```

Comment: How does you linked opencv_nonfree??